# Real-time Tkinter/ttk Entry widget update: thread+queue or .after(1)?

Tags: python, tkinter, real-time, ttk

I have a Tkinter/ttk app that analyzes packets arriving every 10-25 ms.  My present implementation uses a thread that updates 30 StringVars after every socket read, then calls update_idletasks() to update the corresponding Entry widgets.  My app crashes no more than 30 minutes after starting.

Searches revealed that Tk isn't really thread-safe, and I have two main choices:

1. Use a thread + queues.
2. Use a function + .after(1, function).

The UI does little more than start/stop the updates, and provide the Entry widgets for display.

The primary wait in the system is the socket read, which has a timeout of 2x the expected packet rate (so it can't block forever).

In this case, would you prefer approach #1 or #2?

I'm leaning toward #2 for its simplicity, but I'm not sure if there are any Tk gotchas waiting along that path.  I'll probably try both while I await the community wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

My personal rule of thumb is to avoid threads unless they are strictly required. Threads add complexity. Plus, there's a large percentage of programmers who aren't particularly thread-savvy, so threads add an element of risk if this program will be used or maintained by others.

That being said, in this particular case I think I'd go with thread + queues. Since you know how often the display should update, I'd set up a poll of the queue for every 10ms or so to update the widgets.

Comment: If I had a more complex UI, I'd agree!

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented #2 (function + .after(1, function)) by changing literally 8 lines of code in my original implementation, and it runs perfectly.  So #2 wins based on simplicity and effectiveness.  It runs using 3-4% of 1 core (i5-2500, 3.3 GHz)

But if my UI becomes more complex, such as by adding stripchart recording via matplotlib animation, then queues and a separate acquisition thread may become necessary.  But not today!

EDIT: But don't use .after(0, ...): My UI locked up when I tried it.